# Git pre-commit hook issue

Tags: ruby, githooks

I'm a newbie for git hooks. I started writing a pre-commit hook today. Below is my hook which checks for raise, alert, trailing white space in file etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

regex = Regexp.union(/raise/, /puts/, /alert/, /console.log/, /[\s\t]+$/)

folder_path =`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

`git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`.each do |file|
  file_text = File.read(File.join(folder_path.chomp, '/', file))
  if file_text.match(regex)
    puts "#{file} contains invalid word #{$&}. Please remove it"
    exit 1
  end
end
```

while I commit a sample file am getting no such file or directory error.
kranthi@kranthi-Aspire-4755:~/learning/git_learning$ git commit -m "tet"

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit:9:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/kranthi/learning/git_learning/another_folder/test2.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
    from .git/hooks/pre-commit:9
    from .git/hooks/pre-commit:17:in `map'
    from .git/hooks/pre-commit:8:in `each'
    from .git/hooks/pre-commit:8:in `map'
    from .git/hooks/pre-commit:8
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here.

Comment: Would it work without preprending the folder_path? (as in https://github.com/i-wind/gpc/blob/master/pre-commit.rb or https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/pre-commit/0.16.1/files/lib/pre-commit/utils/staged_files.rb)

Comment: working :|. thanks alot. I think I can refer to that pre-commit gem implementation so that I can improve in avoiding such questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by other git hooks (like "[`pre-commit/utils/staged_files.rb`](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/pre-commit/0.16.1/files/lib/pre-commit/utils/staged_files.rb)" or "[`i-wind/gpc/pre-commit.rb`](https://github.com/i-wind/gpc/blob/master/pre-commit.rb)", you don't need to prepend with the root folder of the repo.

```
file_text = File.read(File.join(file))
```